# Backend- How to make a csv file with results available for download in SHINY?

Tags: r, shiny

How to make a csv file written using the below code available to the user for download? How will the user retrieve this file using download button?
write.csv(csv_write, file = "test.csv",row.names=FALSE, na="")

Comment: A quick search gives https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/download.html

Comment: My secondary R script is solving the problem and giving the solution in form of a CSV file. I just want to know how to make that CSV file available for download. The link shows how to download the data from a pre existing database in R. Thank you for the help! :)

Comment: If you use DT in your shinyapp, you can use buttons extension. Check out extensions here: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html.
It's easy to implement, from my experience it's more user-friendly and you can organize them as you want using extend="collections" and putting all desired buttons in a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your server function you can write a download handler :

```
output$downloadData5 <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {'test.csv'},
    content = function(file) {
      write.delim(ftext(), file, row.names = FALSE,sep="\t")
    }
  )
```

Where ftext() is a function which returns your dataframe which you want to download as csv.
Your UI will have a dashboardBody() function in  which you can have the download button:

```
 tabPanel('First Touch Point Campaign Level', 
                 downloadButton('downloadData5', 'Download This Data !!',
                                style="display: block; margin: 0 auto; width: 230px;color: black;"),
                 dataTableOutput('datatable5'))
```

ftext() is the reactive function which returns the dataframe. The code goes like this :

```
 ftext <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    df =   data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE)))     
    return(df)
  })
```

Comment: Thank you @Abhishek Kumar for the prompt response. What would in the ftext() function by which it would return the csv file available for download?

Comment: Thank you. This helps. But what exactly is write.delim?

Comment: Its just like write.csv but instead of comma separated value you can have values separated by any delimiter. You can you use write.csv as well